# Where is the option on Eclipse to define that "{" and "}" will be in the same line and auto autocomplete?

Tags: java, eclipse

i want that pair of brace ('{' and '}') will automatic will be:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{   

}
```

instead of:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 

}
```

and there is way to define the Autocomplete like Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit... -> Braces.

[image: Eclipse with Next Line bracing]

Comment: @user979033: Java -> Editor -> Content Assist. I don't know whether you'll get it *exactly* like VS though.